# Is the CMD history saved after session ends?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

When CMD is used in windows the commands used are saved, My question is if they are written down to permanent storage or just deallocated from the ram with the rest of the CMD process?

Another way of asking this is "if I use a command in CMD will it be saved permanently somewhere?"

Comment: It is clear that the commands are stored somewhere while a cmd session is open. That might be on disk, in the registry, or just in memory. Wherever it is, it is not publicly documented. As a side note, PowerShell console commands do persist across sessions.

Answer (score -1):

To view your history, you can use the F7 key.

Comment: My question is if the history from previous sessions is saved

Comment: I think what Sean tries to communicate is that you can find the answer to your question yourself by executing a few commands, closing the `cmd.exe` process, starting a new `cmd.exe` instance and then pressing F7, observing that your history is indeed lost. However, I agree that such an experiment doesn't prove that your commands aren't saved to a hidden location in your file system, registry, or sent to the NSA. But I am pretty sure that isn't the case.

Comment: while f7 does give the impression that the history is not saved my question was rather about whether windows openly stores the commands (let's assume that there is no secret NSA backdoor etc.)

Comment: @Tom: I understand that. I have never heard of any such feature, and I highly doubt that such a feature exists. You could try to execute a command with a unique string (like `echo SuperstitiousCatecholamine`) and then search for it in the registry and in the file system (`findstr /IS SuperstitiousCatecholamine *.*` in the root).